# Apache PDFBox 1.8.9 doesn't print text (only with some fonts)

Tags: java, text, printing, processing, pdfbox

I'm writing a little program in Processing that uses the PDFBox library to load, edit and save or print pdf files.

The problem is with the printing part. I'm using the .print() method, works everything, but I can't get texts printed.
I noticed that only some random(?) fonts get printed.

When I print the console gives me this:
mag 03, 2015 6:15:52 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFORMAZIONI: unsupported/disabled operation: BDC
mag 03, 2015 6:15:53 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFORMAZIONI: unsupported/disabled operation: EMC
mag 03, 2015 6:15:53 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFORMAZIONI: unsupported/disabled operation: BDC
mag 03, 2015 6:15:53 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFORMAZIONI: unsupported/disabled operation: EMC

If I save the same file that I want to print it has the text (with the right font), and if I print it from another application everithing is fine...

Please HELP T_T
I'm on a MackBookPro 17" 2011 – Yosemite.

Comment: 1.8.9 can't render some type 1 fonts and some TT fonts properly, this is solved in the (unreleased but available with svn https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#scm ) 2.0 version. The cause is broken java font handling. If you upload your PDF file somewhere I can test it in 2.0. Btw the INFORMAZIONI texts are harmless.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you for the reply :) But I have to do some dumb questions since I'm pretty ignorant in programming.

Which path should I follow to get the 2.0.0 api?

Here is the code if you want to take a look: [link] (https://mega.co.nz/#!Z1s0TRoB!mIf4Y1BqeNJ5b2Z6X70qwlPr5RbDt6cAaLsTwAFSO-s)

Comment: The link downloads a file named ABApp_v4.zip. There are at least three different PDF files. Which is these is the one that makes trouble? Can it be viewed with Adobe Reader?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The ABApp generates a logo and puts it on a PDF selected at runtime.
(the 3 buttons under the logo preview are for saving, the middle one is for choosing a PDF and saving the modified version and the one on the right for choosing a PDF and directly print it after the modifications).

Comment: But which of the files in the ZIP is the one you can't print? I don't wan to run your entire application to test one single file.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr PDFs inside the zip are for internal uses, not for printing. The problem is with every PDFs' texts in general, sorry if I can't explain well the problem...

Comment: OK, with 2.0.0 everything is fine, thank you for your help and patience :)